# How to avoid round to next whole number in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I want to make a report with retail price. The retail price are in decimal values. Now i want to get the whole number as like:
For example

- 61.90 as 61
- 78.93 as 71
- 45.65 as 45

this format. anyone let u know. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use following functions to round down:

```
int(61.90) = 61
floor(61.90,1) = 61
```

Comment: I am using field value for 61.90 . Then how to use this code. i Mean vw_totalvalue= 61.90 it may vary for different values.

Comment: put your field in the functions. int(vw_totalvalue) or floor(vw_totalvalue)

Comment: after int() . i changed the format of fields to decimal place 1. it works fine.

Comment: Perfect. I just tested floor(vw_totalvalue,1) that worked fine as well.